How to recover data after domain controller failed
Our domain controller crashed and we have no way of recovering it. Our  computers authenticated and connected to our old domain controller, and roaming profiles were disabled. Our users save  files locally in  c:\users\mylocaluser\ and used the domain controller for authentication to the network.
Now, we need to recover the files of a local user, but when we authenticate to our new domain controller, the old files are gone.
We tried to install the hard drive to another pc, but still the files seem to be gone.
I searched and found that perhaps the files may be at c:\windows\csc, but we can not have access to that folder. So we are stuck.
Have you ever experienced a similar problem?

the old files are gone.
You created a new Active Directory with new user accounts. When a new account logs on, it has a new profile, not the profile of the user account from the destroyed Active Directory. So a person with administrator access to the workstation needs to logon and copy the files from the old profile to the new profile.

Thank you for you answer. To make things easier and simpler, we just need to restore the files from the old computer. We removed the hard drive and installed it as a secondary on a new machine(not connected to the new domain) but we can not see any of the old profiles or files.

No need to remove any hard drive. The files are on the workstation hard drive in the old user profile directory.

Ok thank so much

Check if any folder rediraction policy had been forces in domain.
If yes, then check the folder path which is set for folder redirection, where the data is stored.
